# Application Defined or Object-Defined Error

Tags: vba

I am trying to set the border and interior formatting of cells in column F using vba. Whether or not their formatting gets changed depends on whether there is any information in the cell directly above and/or below it. I have been using the following code to do this:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = worksheets("Res")

Dim c As Range
For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns("F").Cells
If IsEmpty(c.Offset(1, 0)) = True And IsEmpty(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = False Then
    With c.Offset(-1, 0).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 5
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With c.Offset(-1, 0).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
Next c
```

At the

```
If IsEmpty(c.Offset(1, 0)) = True And IsEmpty(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = False Then
```

I have been getting the error:

> Application Defined or Object-Defined Error

Does anyone know why that is?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are likely starting at the first cell in the column so attempting to offset *up* with `-1` is not possible & would raise that error.

Add a check to ensure `c.Row > 1` to guard against this.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might have something to do with it. Can you elaborate on where I should add the c.row > 1? I tried putting: "If c.Row > 1 And IsEmpty(c.Offset(1, 0)) = True And IsEmpty(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = False Then...", but I got the same error.